# Does Xamarin support Windows 10?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, windows-10, cross-platform

I tried several times to make Xamarin work in Visual Studio with Windows 10 and it doesn't. After creating a solution with Cross-Platform Xamarin.Forms.Portable none of the projects compile. All of them, apart from the UWP project, has alarms for example the Android project shows the alarm that it can't connect in the debugger. I have read in several forums that it doesn't work on Windows 10. Any idea?

Update:
This is an old question for a deprecated version. The issue was on the version used.

Comment: `The minimum operating system version is Windows 7. Xamarin.Forms Windows support requires Windows 8.1, and Xamarin.Forms UWP support requires Windows 10.` @ https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/requirements/#Windows_Requirements

Comment: @SushiHangover exactly. It suppose that it should work but it doesn't. Did it happen to you too?

Comment: @FotiosTragopoulos I've been using it on Windows 10 for quite some time now... no problems here

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You can read from the Internet that all products have defects, and then so what? Everything should break on every machine? Clearly Windows 10 is supported by Xamarin as development environment, https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/requirements/#windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem with the solution I find to this blogspot. http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.gr/2016/02/fix-for-could-not-connect-to-debugger.html

It is a problem occurs on the new generation processors.

Answer (score 2):

I have used Xamarin with Visual Studio on Windows 10.

My setup is as follows:

- Parallels Desktop (Allows you to run windows on the Mac)
- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2015
- Windows 10
- Xamarin Studio 6.0.1 (with accounts activated online)

For Android:

- Android SDK must be installed and the path configured.
- During compile time Visual Studio will pull down the assemblies needed for the 
  Api version you set the Android Project to.

For iOS:

- You need access to a Mac to build.
- The Mac should also have Xamarin Studio Installed, this will include a build server Visual Studio connects to.

For Windows Phone:

- You need the Windows Phone Sdk installed.